# Reconstruction loss function of VAE

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am learning from an example given by TensorFlow document, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae#define_the_loss_function_and_the_optimizer:

> VAEs train by maximizing the evidence lower bound (ELBO) on the
> marginal log-likelihood.
>
> In practice, optimize the single sample Monte Carlo estimate of this
> expectation: logp(x|z) + logp(z) - logq(z|x).

The loss function was implemented as:

```
def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
  log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
  return tf.reduce_sum(
      -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi),
      axis=raxis)


def compute_loss(model, x):
  mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
  z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
  x_logit = model.decode(z)
  cross_ent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x_logit, labels=x)
  logpx_z = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_ent, axis=[1, 2, 3])
  logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
  logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
  return -tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x)
```

Since this example used MINIST dataset, `x` can be normalized to [0, 1] and `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` was used here.

### My questions are:

1. What if `x > 1`, what kind of loss could be used?
2. Can we use other loss functions as a reconstruction loss in VAE, such as Huber loss (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss)?
3. Another example used MSE loss (as follow), is MSE loss a valid `ELBO` loss to measure p(x|z)?

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#putting_it_all_together_an_end-to-end_example

```
    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, x_batch_train in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            reconstructed = vae(x_batch_train)
            # Compute reconstruction loss
            loss = mse_loss_fn(x_batch_train, reconstructed)
            loss += sum(vae.losses)  # Add KLD regularization loss
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loss function of a variational autoencoder, you jointly optimize two terms:

1. The reconstruction loss between prediction and label, like in a normal autoencoder
2. The distance between the parametrized probability distribution and the assumed true probability distribution. In practice, the true distribution is usually assumed to be Gaussian and distance is measured in terms of Kullback-Leibler divergence

For the reconstruction loss part, you can pick any loss function that fits your data, including MSE and Huber. It is generally still a good idea to normalize your input features though.